# Regex matches incorrect value

Tags: c#, regex

I am using C#. I need regex to examine text like that:

```
abc {val2:123} lorem ipsum {val1:234}
```

I need to match all the **{x:y}**. I've tried regex **{.*}** but it matches the whole value - "**{val2:123} lorem ipsum {val1:234}**". Of course It's not fun.

How to change my regex approppriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\{([^}]*)\}
```

This matches a `{` followed by zero or more characters that are not a `}` then it matches a literal `}`, it puts whatever that was matched into group 1.

You can then split the captured group on the colon symbol `:` to get the key and value pair.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sY1eY5)

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich You are welcome, thank you for liking this variant :)

Answer (score 4):

```
string input = "abc {val2:123} lorem ipsum {val1:234}";
var dict = Regex.Matches(input, @"\{(.+?):(.+?)\}").Cast<Match>()
            .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Although, It would be useful to explain what lazy/non-greedy matching is.

Answer (score 2):

```
{(?<param>\w+):(?<value>\w+)}
```

The above should work... I've already included named groups to make selecting values easier.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because c sharp regex is greedy by default. Just use **{.*?}**

The following code will do exactly what you want. That's all about that question mark that makes the regex nongreegy.

```
string s = "abc {val2:123} lorem ipsum {val1:234};";
MatchCollection nonGreedyMatches = Regex.Matches(s, @"{.*?}");
```